# C# implementation of Dictionary to Create an index of words

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dictionary, indexing, text-processing

I'm currently trying to create an application to do some text processing to read in a text file, then I use a dictionary to create index of words, reading  a text file and checking to see if the word is already in that file or not. If so, it will print out the index number and continue the check.

I've tried to implement some code to create the dictionary. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
 private void bagofword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {  //creating dictionary in background
    Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    string rawinputbow = File.ReadAllText(textBox31.Text);
    string[] inputbow = rawinputbow.Split(' ');
        foreach (String word in inputbow)
        {
            if (dict.ContainsKey(word))
            {
                dict[word]++;
            }
            else
            {
                dict[word] = 1;
            }
        }
        var ordered = from k in dict.Keys
                      orderby dict[k] descending
                      select k;

        using (StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter("D:\\output.txt"))
        {
            foreach (String k in ordered)
            {
                output.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", k, dict[k]));
            }
            output.Close();
        }  
    }
```

Here is an example of the text file I'm inputting: `http://pastebin.com/ZRVbhWhV`
A quick `ctrl-F` shows that "not" occurs 2 times and "that" occurs 4 times. What I need to do is to index each word and call it in like this:

> ```
>    sample input : "that I have not had not that place" 
>
>       dictionary :              output.txt:
>         index word                    5 
>           1    I                      1 
>           2   have                    2
>           3   had                     4
>           4   not                     3
>           5   that                    4
>           6   place                   5
>                                       6
> ```

Does anyone know how to complete that code? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `output.Close()` is redundant in the `using` statement.  `output` will be closed when the `using` block is exited.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem that you are running into?

Comment: Just record the words in order to a List and do a a lookup to the count.

Comment: @TyCobb See the if else ContainsKey

Comment: @Blam yup and it looks like there is no add. So issue is probably key does not exist. But would be nice to actually know the issue....

Comment: I don't know what file sizes you plan on dealing with, but loading the whole thing into memory is not going to scale well.  Thinking about using a stream reader to read thru the file.

Comment: @Christopherous5000 And just how do you .Split a stream reader?

Comment: @Blam, You can read in each line into memory at a time and split the line, adding results to the same dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var txt = "that i have not had not that place"
        .Split(" ".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .ToList();

    var dict = new OrderedDictionary();
    var output = new List<int>();

    foreach (var element in txt.Select ((word,index) => new{word,index}))
    {
        if (dict.Contains(element.word))
        {
            var count = (int)dict[element.word];
            dict[element.word] = ++count;
            output.Add(GetIndex(dict,element.word));
        }
        else
        {
            dict[element.word] = 1;
            output.Add(GetIndex(dict,element.word));
        }
    }
}

public int GetIndex(OrderedDictionary dictionary, string key) 
{
    for (int index = 0; index < dictionary.Count; index++)
    {
        if (dictionary[index] == dictionary[key]) 
            return index; // We found the item
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Results:

dict = (6 items)

```
that = 2 
i = 1 
have = 1 
not = 2 
had = 1 
place = 1
```

Output = (8 items)

```
0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
3 
0 
5
```

Comment: Oh,. I was thinking about using Ordered dictionary but did i should input Ordered dictionary class instead? and sorry for bothering you with so much question because i am a new  one at this topics. thank you @Charles,

Comment: @Indiastradi, I'm not sure what your asking?  The code does what you needed it to do?

Comment: oh here what i mean ,when i try your code i keep find something error with the "var dict = new OrderedDictionary();" .. its says that "the type or namespace name 'OrderedDictionary' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference) ?" so to fix this error should i create a Class of Ordered Dictionary? thank you again @Charles

Comment: @Indiastradi What framework version are you using.  I think OrderedDictionary was introduced in 4.5/4.6 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: oh ok @Charles.. i see .., currently i'm working on 4.0 but after i changes the framework version to 4.5 its still have some error that give 3 item to choose. first, to insert  'System.Collections.Specialized', or insert  'System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary' or creating a new class. can you give me suggestion for this ?

Comment: oh sorry @Charles for bothering you with such easy one. now i see i should put 'using System.Collections.Specialized;' as soon as i change the framework version. thank you for that's great answer! :)

Comment: hi @Charles, i have implement your code but lately i realize ... when i call output, with this code :
textBoxfile.Text = output.ToString();                                                         
to write the output into textbox then something like this will comes 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' in the text box that its should be the output. sorry for asking this easy one but can you help me to complete this code ? thank you ..

Comment: @Indiastradi, use string.join(",",output);

Comment: Hi @Charles, could you help for this time ... recently i have improve my code above to give an output like this  http://pastebin.com/CjtcYchF which it contain "[word index in dict]:[count of occurence]", but i got some problem to indexing and get the dictionary like you do before. so could you give me some suggestion to print out that dictionary file from your answer above ? Thank you

Comment: here what i have so far : pastebin.com/y7xZXVzt .. but i got this error , when i try to run it ...: "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator2[System.Linq.IGrouping2[‌​System.String,System.String],CobaTugasAkhir2.Form1+word] " 
 thank you

Comment: @Indiastradi, var wrodList = input.Split(null).  You are trying to Split a List.  Lists cannot be split.

Comment: yeah your right but actually i ask this question in other column, and i got some answer to improve my code like that, its the question link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362427/count-the-number-of-unique-words-and-occurrence-of-each-word-from-txt-file/32362851?noredirect=1#comment53158366_32362851 . but i got an error and stuck at some point, so would you mind to help me ? thank you :)

Comment: @Indiastradi Try asking your question in a new question and include the code you are having problems with.  Then let me know where I can see completely what you have and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: here the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32729264/indexing-unique-word-for-lda-input , sorry for bothering you. and thank you :)

Comment: hi ... I try to solve my latest problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32729264/indexing-unique-word-for-lda-input, and figure out something ... How can I print out an ordered dictionary like that answer ? I mean the dictionary in word not an index ..